# Understanding Enums in Java

Tags: java, enum

In the book [Effective Java](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683) its told that:

> The basic idea behind Java’s enum types is simple: they are classes that export
>   one instance for each enumeration constant via a public static final field. Enum
>   types are effectively final, by virtue of having no accessible constructors.

So, if I have an enum like:

`public enum Orange {NAVEL, TEMPLE, BLOOD}`

Then, it must be similar to:

```
public class Orange implements Comparable , implements Serializable {
    private Orange() {}

    public static final Orange NAVEL = new Orange();
    public static final Orange TEMPLE = new Orange();
    public static final Orange BLOOD = new Orange();

    public int compareTo(Orange other) {}
}
```

To this point it seems fine, but after some time the examples get over complicated, for example I am still puzzled over the following `enum` definition.

```
public enum Ensemble {
    SOLO(1), DUET(2), TRIO(3), QUARTET(4), QUINTET(5),
    SEXTET(6), SEPTET(7), OCTET(8), DOUBLE_QUARTET(8),
    NONET(9), DECTET(10), TRIPLE_QUARTET(12);

    private final int numberOfMusicians;

    Ensemble(int size) {
        this.numberOfMusicians = size;
    }

    public int numberOfMusicians() {
        return numberOfMusicians;
    }
}
```

What could be its similar class equivalent and is there a `length` property on it?

Comment: You can list all values of your enum using [values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13659231/784594) static method, which returns an array. It hten provides length property.

Comment: @OndrejM an example will never hurt anyone :)

Comment: I wanted to encourage you to study :) Anyway, an example goes like this: `Ensemble.values().length`

Comment: This is off-topic and probably more suitable for StackOverflow (where it could get closed anyway), but it's too old to migrate.

Comment: @AndresF. I disagree. While it does have code in it, the goal is to understand how enums are similar to "regular" classes in Java at a conceptual level. The compiler makes enums inherit from [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) and adds some syntactical sugar and boilerplate code to the class definition. This is not very intuitive to a beginner who is diving into using enums without reading all of the (unnecessary) documentation on them.

Comment: @AndresF. I don't know from where you get this idea, but the question itself is very valid and does contains valid reasoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter example corresponds to a class like this:

```
public final class Ensemble {
    public static final Ensemble SOLO = new Ensemble(1);
    public static final Ensemble DUET = new Ensemble(2);
    public static final Ensemble TRIO = new Ensemble(3);
    ...
    public static final Ensemble TRIPLE_QUARTET = new Ensemble(12);

    private final int numberOfMusicians;

    private Ensemble(int size) {
        this.numberOfMusicians = size;
    }

    public int numberOfMusicians() {
        return numberOfMusicians;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I need to have `final` keyword too while emulating `enums` since it can't be inherited, right?

Comment: Correct. The reason for making the class final is that enums can't be extended. There are some features of enums which are not covered in this example: enums are Comparable, they provide a static values method etc. So, if you really want to write a class that emulates an enum thoroughly, more needs to be done. This example covers only the use of a private constructor for creating constants.

Comment: Update: having `private constructor` also prevents sub-classing why we need `final` then?

Comment: @vivek Yes, if a class doesn't have any accessible constructors, then it is effectively final. However, it's good practice to communicate your design choices explicitly. The Java compiler doesn't really need `final` here but we as programmers need `final` to make it clear that the class we've written is not supposed to be sub-classed. Trying to extend a non-final class that has no visible constructors can be slightly confusing. The compiler will not tell you that the class can't be sub-classed but rather advice you to do something that's really not possible. Try it out.